# Script that can make HTML page change if it hasn't been touched in a while?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm in my first year of compsci and i have to make a website. I want to make it more unique by giving it a secret feature where if my lecturer opens the page, keeps it open, doesnt touch it, comes back like 5 mins later and its a completely different and unique page. Is there a js or html script that can do this? Any help is much appreciated

I've tried to search it up but perhaps what I want is too specific? cause i cant find anything

Comment: Have you made a start on this? Where are you stuck? Is your "secret feature" only to be activated if it's your lecturer visiting the page (what logic are you using to determine if it is, or is not, the lecturer?), or should it change after five minutes of inactivity for any user? How different should it be, what does "unique" mean in this context? "*...[because I] can't find anything*" - then generalise your search queries, changing content in the DOM is a fairly major use-case of JavaScript.

Comment: I'm stuck in that I don't know anything about how to do it and it's just an idea for now...... So the "secret feature" should activate regardless of who's accessing the content. Different and unique as in changing the page completely and redirecting to a whole different html file. And I'll look into the changing content in the DOM thx

Comment: Do you just want to change the content or redirect to other page?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to create a secret feature on your website that changes the page content after a specific time period when certain conditions are met. To achieve this, you can use JavaScript along with some HTML. Here's a basic outline of how you can implement this:

HTML: Create two versions of the page content, one for the initial state and another for the changed state. Wrap each version in a separate container with unique IDs. For example:

```
<div id="initial-content">
  <!-- Your initial page content goes here -->
</div>

<div id="changed-content" style="display: none;">
  <!-- Your changed page content goes here -->
</div>
```

JavaScript: Add a script tag in your HTML file or link an external JavaScript file. Use the setTimeout function to execute a callback after a specific time delay. Check if the page is being viewed by your lecturer (e.g., by checking the user agent or IP address).

```
<script>
  // Check if the page is accessed by the lecturer
  function isLecturer() {
    // Implement your logic to determine if the user is the lecturer
    // For example, you can check the user agent or IP address
    return true; // Replace with your logic
  }

  // Function to change the page content
  function changePageContent() {
    if (isLecturer()) {
      // Replace initial content with the changed content
      document.getElementById('initial-content').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('changed-content').style.display = 'block';
    }
  }

  // Set a timer to change the page content
  setTimeout(changePageContent, 300000); // 300000ms = 5 minutes
</script>
```

In the above code, the isLecturer function is a placeholder for your logic to determine if the user accessing the page is your lecturer. You can modify this function to suit your requirements, such as checking the user agent, IP address, or using some authentication mechanism.

The changePageContent function is called after the specified delay using setTimeout. If the isLecturer function returns true, it will hide the initial content and display the changed content.

Remember to replace the placeholders ( and ) with your actual content.

This code should give you a starting point to achieve the desired functionality. Feel free to modify it based on your specific needs and design preferences.

Comment: how did you comment so fast....
anyways sorry but I don't really understand it. When I put a p tag with different text into both initial and changed content divs, they both showed up, I don't really understand that part. Also I'm thinking more of a timer and then the whole page will change instead of just the content because my website needs more pages to hit the criteria. but if that's not possible changing the content is fine too but I just don't understand what you said is it possible to make it more basic... sorry

Comment: my bad about both div shows i have changed the code now. i just gave you hint how you can change entire page. if you page is too big then i recomanded use backend from where you retrive html of page and send request to server after 5 seocnd to get new html then replace entire body with new html tag

Comment: Here's a running example: https://jsfiddle.net/4tmqg2ca/

Comment: @PathoGen the answer was most likely copy/pasted from ChatGPT rather than written by the user

Comment: Bro i typed so much fast you saying chatGPT, it's wast of my best today

Comment: Update: Wait, you said "if it hasn't been touched". Sorry! My example will always change after a set time. You could write a simple implementation by checking for any keydown events or click events and then triggering the same kind of change. Or use something like https://idletimer.dev/ if you're using React (or find a similar lib for your framework / plain js).

Comment: The writing in the answer and the writing in your comments are not from the same source @JigneshSanghani. You should understand [that LLM answers are banned here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned) and you risk the possibility of having your account banned too.

Comment: yes that's becuse before answering here i did recheck english with gpt but my logic my own and typing slow gpt just might added 2 line and corrected english

Comment: @computerman Wish your comment was an answer instead so I can give you a solve but thanks so much for the help man. Even your previous example of the timer with no idle feature worked well enough man. Thx so much bro I'll credit you in a comment in my file so my teacher knows who the goat is 

Comment: I don't have a problem with that @JigneshSanghani. In fact that is a great use of CPT3, don't get me wrong. What I find odd is that you managed to write all of that code and explanatory text, and do the spelling check, in three minutes.

Comment: i have used GPT4 and in my vscode has co pilot integration so when i see question i always in hurry to give answer first so i did code in 1 minute then i type few line which i need to describe then asked GPT4 to correct me with best writing practice of stackoverflow